# Including a file from zend view

Tags: php, zend-framework, charts

I am kind of in a mess ! I need to know how to access a file from the view. 
My folder structure :

```
application
 -controllers
 -models
 -views
  -helpers
  -scripts
   -report
     index.phtml
     sample.inc
```

Now If i need to access this file from index.phtml , for an example `fopen('sample.inc','w+');` fails. Do i have to give the full path here ? I am having this problem for a lot of situations in the view. This sample.inc is a file to be used by PHP/SWF charts.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Gayan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read a file like that, you should specify in which directory it is.

You could use one of those two solutions, in your `index.phtml` file, to access the `sample.inc` file, using its full path :

- `dirname(__FILE__) . '/sample.inc'`
- `__DIR__ . '/sample.inc'` -- PHP >= 5.3

Both [`dirname(__FILE__)`](https://www.php.net/dirname) and [`__DIR__`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) point to the directory that contains the file in which they are used.

Just using `sample.inc`, PHP is searching in the *current directory* -- which is not the `report` one, when your code gets executed.

Comment: @martin What you mean here is if I use the above options , I am explicitly telling PHP where my file is ?

Comment: Yes: you'll be using a full path *(that include the directory, its parent directory and so on)*, and not just a file name -- try echoing that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What you wand to do is called a "view partial", see
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial. Beside, I suggest to rename `sample.inc` to `sample.partial.phtml`, to follow the Zend Framework naming convetions.

However, when using view partials, you need to specify the parameters that you want to pass to the partial and you can specify the path as a path relative to the view script path, so i guess this should work:

```
<?php
echo $this->partial('report/sample.partial.phtml', array(
    'var1' => $this->var1,
    'var2' => $this->var2)); 
?>
```

An alternative approach would be using the render() method - that way you simply render the specified view script in the scope of the current view, so you sould have all variables from the current view object:

```
<?php
echo $this->render('report/sample.partial.phtml'); 
?>
```

Hope it helps :)